# Whole webpage refreshes after invoking process

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-2.7, electron, zerorpc

I am having this issue: https://youtu.be/Gqo_QpsKMNU. After doing a lot of debugging I realized that the problem is caused by the client.invoke process.

```
client.invoke("inicializar", (error, res) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error("No pude generar nuevo archivo en blanco de reglas", error)
  } else {
    leer(res)
  }
})
```

When it is called the webpage refreshes, and I don't want it to. Does anybody know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: If you comment out the `leer(res)` does it happen? Hard to know from that little bit of code.

Comment: @epascarello yes it does, as I say it is caused by the zerorpc invoke method... And there's nothing on the zerorpc repo about this issue